# Edit/Unlock Bash_profile

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, bash

I'm trying to edit my .bash_profile and it keeps saying it's locked out. How do I unlock/edit my .bash_profile?

I tried doing this, but it didn't work.

```
sudo chown my_user_name ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /Users/yourusername/.bash_profile
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown yourusername /Users/yourusername/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Type that into Terminal?

Comment: Sorry, unfamiliar with alot of terminal stuff. When I attempt to open the bash_profile: `open ~/.bash_profile` it opens a new terminal shell and logs me out. However, I'm trying to open it in a text editor and edit the file.

$ /Users/myusername/.bash_profile ; exit;
logout

[Process completed]

Comment: Yes, you can paste those two lines into terminal to see if it will unlock your .bash_profile, replacing "yourusername" with your actual username. Try that and let me know if you can then open the file. You could open it (to edit) by using `open -a "TextEdit.app" ~/.bash_profile`